# If my code references an assembly when built, do I need to distribute it?

Tags: .net, clr, assemblies

I have some common code that runs on two types of machines:

- .NET 2.0 full framework on server type machines
- .NET 2.0 Compact Framework on Windows CE devices

I have a feature that is being added to the full framework devices, but that code isn't going to run for compact framework devices.

Do I still need to distribute the referenced dll to the Windows CE devices?

After thinking about it, since the code is in different files, I'll just omit the files from the Windows CE solution, but I'd still like the question above answered from a technical perspective.

Mark

Answer (score 0):

If you reference your library using early binding (Right click on project -> Add Reference), you would need to distribute it along with the code. This is due to the fact that the code’s metadata would be referring to the referenced library. To make the matters even more interesting if the referenced library references other libraries in the same manner, they should also be available for the CLR to locate and load..

But, if you use a technique such as reflection and discover and do the binding in runtime, you will be able to load the application without CLR being able to find the library till your code needs it (call it via reflection)

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't have to even if you use some code sometimes :-)
E.g. if you use constants or enums, you don't need dll, unless you use code that is using type of enum.
So in general if you have code, that is not run, you may not distribute dll.
But sometimes you may have typeloadexception, if your code is like this

```
if (condition)
  use type from another library
else
 use type from current library
```

If condition not some compilation dependent constant, JITer may not make correct assumption, that
code will not run, then it will try to load the type, and then you have exception.
In such cases I would use conditional compilation, like this

```
#if COMPACT
//use type here
#else
//not use type here
#endif
```